# catching YUI events between sandboxes

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I have two different sandboxes of YUI:

```
YUI().use(){

var drag = new Y.DD.Delegate({ 
    nodes: '#userlist li', 
    dragConfig: { 
        dragMode: 'point', 
        groups: ['participants'] } });

}
```

and

```
YUI().use(){
//i can't get the drag:hit event in this sandbx
}
```

in one i create a drag object and on the other i create a drop object. 
If the code is executed on the same YUI sandbox then everything works, but if i take the code of the drop object and place it in the second YUI sandbox i don't get the drop:hit event.

how can i make this event global?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#broadcast

Comment: can you do that for YUI events? can i do something like this:
 var drag = new Y.DD.Delegate({
        nodes: '#userlist li',
        dragConfig: {
            dragMode: 'point',
            groups: ['participants']
        }
    });

drag.publish("drag:hit", {
        broadcast:  2,   // global notification
        emitFacade: false
    });

Answer (score 1):

FYI: The answer can now be found here http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event-custom/#broadcasting-events-to-y-or-between-yui-instances